# Socket Server Example with Swift

Tags: macos, sockets, swift

I tried to make an example of simple socket server.

Build and run successfully.  However it doesn't work well.

Client couldn't connect to this server.

How to solve this problem?  I need your help, thanks.

```
import Foundation

let BUFF_SIZE = 1024

func initStruct<S>() -> S {
    let struct_pointer = UnsafePointer<S>.alloc(1)
    let struct_memory = struct_pointer.memory
    struct_pointer.destroy()
    return struct_memory
}

func sockaddr_cast(p: ConstUnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>) -> UnsafePointer<sockaddr> {
    return UnsafePointer<sockaddr>(p)
}

func socklen_t_cast(p: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> UnsafePointer<socklen_t> {
    return UnsafePointer<socklen_t>(p)
}

var server_socket: Int32
var client_socket: Int32
var server_addr_size: Int
var client_addr_size: Int

var server_addr: sockaddr_in = initStruct()
var client_addr: sockaddr_in = initStruct()

var buff_rcv: Array<CChar> = []
var buff_snd: String

server_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if server_socket == -1
{
    println("[Fail] Create Server Socket")
    exit(1)
}
else
{
    println("[Success] Created Server Socket")
}

server_addr_size = sizeof(server_addr.dynamicType)
memset(&server_addr, 0, UInt(server_addr_size));

server_addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
server_addr.sin_port = 4000
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = UInt32(0x00000000)    // INADDR_ANY = (u_int32_t)0x00000000 ----- <netinet/in.h>

let bind_server = bind(server_socket, sockaddr_cast(&server_addr), socklen_t(server_addr_size))

if bind_server == -1
{
    println("[Fail] Bind Port");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    println("[Success] Binded Port");
}

if listen(server_socket, 5) == -1
{
    println("[Fail] Listen");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    println("[Success] Listening : \(server_addr.sin_port) Port ...");
}

var n = 0

while n < 1
{
    client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr.dynamicType)
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, sockaddr_cast(&client_addr), socklen_t_cast(&client_addr_size))

    if client_socket == -1
    {
        println("[Fail] Accept Client Connection");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        println("[Success] Accepted Client : \(inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)) : \(client_addr.sin_port)");
    }

    read(client_socket, &buff_rcv, UInt(BUFF_SIZE))

    println("[Success] Received : \(buff_rcv)")

    buff_snd = "\(strlen(buff_rcv)) : \(buff_rcv)"

    write(client_socket, &buff_snd, strlen(buff_snd) + 1)

    close(client_socket)
}
```

Comment: have you cleaned up your code? I would use it also, I get an error at this line: `let struct_pointer = UnsafePointer<S>.alloc(1)` **does not have  a member named alloc**

Comment: This thread is rather old, but for anyone coming here looking for an up-to-date Swift socket package this might be what you want: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket

Comment: Another possibility is this one: https://github.com/Balancingrock/SwifterSockets

Answer (score 4):

The port number in the socket address must be in big-endian byte order:

```
server_addr.sin_port = UInt16(4000).bigEndian
```

So your program actually listens on port 40975 (hex 0xA00F) and not
on port 4000 (hex 0x0FA0).

Another problem is here:

```
var buff_rcv: Array<CChar> = []
// ...
read(client_socket, &buff_rcv, UInt(BUFF_SIZE))
```

Your buffer is an *empty* array, but `recv()` expects a buffer of size `BUFF_SIZE`.
The behaviour is undefined. To get a buffer of the required size, use

```
var buff_rcv = [CChar](count:BUFF_SIZE, repeatedValue:0)
// ...
read(client_socket, &buff_rcv, UInt(buff_rcv.count))
```

*Remark:* Here you cast the address of an `Int` to the address of an `socklen_t`
and pass that to the `accept()` function:

```
client_socket = accept(server_socket, sockaddr_cast(&client_addr), socklen_t_cast(&client_addr_size))
```

That is not safe. If `Int` and `socklen_t` have different sizes then the behaviour
will be undefined. You should declare `server_addr_size` and `client_addr_size`
as `socklen_t` and remove the `socklen_t_cast()` function:

```
client_socket = accept(server_socket, sockaddr_cast(&client_addr), &client_addr_size)
```

Comment: There are actually more problems in your code. For example `buff_snd` is a Swift `String`. You cannot simply treat that as a `char` buffer in `write(client_socket, &buff_snd, strlen(buff_snd) + 1)`.

Comment: Martin, could you recommend an easy implementation of socket server implemented in Swift that receives and responds strings? socket tutorial below claims, that only 4 method should be implemented, (socket, bind, listen, accept) but all the solution I checked out in SO and github are are so  complex, differs from each other and overcomplicated http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html

Comment: @János: Server socket programming isn't easy (at least if you want to handle multiple connections concurrently). GCDAsyncSocket (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is a nice wrapper written in Objective-C and can be used  from Swift, but I do not have any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin R commented before, the write command shouldn't be using the swift string as that. Something like this will work properly:

```
write(client_socket, buff_snd.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, countElements(buff_snd) + 1)
```